# Has_secure_password and only one defined account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `has_secure_password` to authorization. I want to create only one user account (admin) and that's all. Visitor can't create new account.
He can just logign as a admin if he has correct login and password.

But where should I defined this login and password for admin?
I have user model but I haven't got idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need 1 admin user with login/password, then you can just use  [HTTP Digest Authentication](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-digest-authentication), which is supported by rails out-of-the-box and doesn't require any extra gems or plugins.

In your `users_controller.rb`:

```
USERS = { "admin" => "password" }

before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :show]

# actions here (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy) 

private
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest do |username|
      USERS[username]
    end
  end
end
```

Then, only the admin with correct login/password will be able to login to see the website content.